# only 1st img is display onclick of link for multiple modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

The images are fetched from the PHP PDO database from the directory "Images" where there are multiple images in it using SQL queries. When I try to click on the source link of the image and try to open the modal image, only the first image is been viewed by all other images too. I tried to change the ID names, but still it is showing the same first page. I have attached my code and the output below. Requesting anyone to help me in this and also the procedure to change the ID values.

```
    if($data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    // to display all the images from the given condition
        {
            $link_id=0;
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                //$img=$row['images'];
                $id=$row['id'];
                $link_id=$link_id+1;
                $query="SELECT images FROM pictures WHERE id=$id";
                $stmt2=$conn->query($query);
                $pictures=$stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach($pictures as $rowimg)
                {
                    $img=$rowimg['images'];
                    ?>               
                    <b><a id='<?php echo $link_id;?>' class='link_class' onclick='myfunc();'> <?php echo $img;?> </a></b>
                    <br><br>
                    <div id='modal_id' class='modal_class'>
                        <div class='modal_content_class'>
                          <img  id='<?php echo $id;?>' class='img_class'  src="images/<?php echo $img;?>" width='300' height='260'>
                          <span  id='close_id' class='close_class' onclick="modal.style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                                     
                    <script>
                                            
                    var modal = document.getElementById("modal_id");
                    var closebtn =modal.getElementsByClassName("close_class");
                                            
                    function myfunc()
                    {
                        modal.style.display='block';
                        document.getElementById('<?php echo $id; ?>'). src="images/<?php echo $img;?>";
                        console.log(123);
                    };

                    </script> 
            }
        }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtlI.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3I2I.png)

Comment: Every loop you create a new `myfunc` function, overriding the last. Only the last function will ever be called. You should create a single function and call it with a parameter that identifies the image to be shown.

Comment: You also create a modal each loop. Every one has the same `modal_id` ID. Only the _first_ modal in the document will ever be found by `document.getElementById("modal_id")`.

Comment: I tried using parameter but i am getting error. How to use the php parameters in **onclick='myfunc(parameter);** for the image to be shown?